# How to get current I18n scope of the template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a function:

```
def some_func(current_i18n_scope)
  #...
  name = I18n.t("name",scope:current_i18n_scope)
  #...
end
```

which is accessible in the template:

```
# app/views/foo/index.html.erb
  ...
  <%= t(".other") %>
  <%= some_func(current_i18n_scope_template) %> 
  ...

# config/locales/foo.yml
en:
  foo:
    index:
      name: Amigo
      other: Other value
```

How I can get `current_i18n_scope_template` in the template and send it to `some_func` function as param?

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a quite old question, but here is how I solved a similar issue.

The ActionView::TranslationsHelper is using a private method 'scope_key_by_partial':

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/56832e791f3ec3e586cf049c6408c7a183fdd3a1/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb#L123

You can see how this method is using the @virtual_path instance variable (provided by ActionView::Context) to scope keys starting with '.'

To simply get the scope you could do something like:

```
def current_i18n_scope
  @virtual_path.gsub(%r{/_?}, ".") 
end
```